# Deciding which given function represents wave function?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, differentiation

I have been given four functions:

1. $u(x, t) = (x + 3t^3)^{1/3}$
2. $u(x,t) = 2\cos(5t)\sin(5x)$
3. $u(x,t)=(x−5t)^2 + \exp(\cos(5t+x))$
4. $u(x,t)=x^2\cos(7x−t)$

None of them seems to satisfy the standard wave equation. The question however ask me to decide which of them represents possible solutions of the one dimension wave equation, stating the appropriate value of the wave speed $c$ in each case. Also, if the possible solution represent right-propagating waves, left-propagating waves, a linear combination of right or left propagating waves or standing waves.

Comment: By 'the standard wave equation' do you mean $(\partial_{tt} - c^2 \partial_{xx})u=0$?

Comment: With the *standard wave equation* $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = c^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$ the answer should be easy to find.

Comment: I think you should check again. I see at least one that would work

Comment: 3 and especially 2 look symmetrically enough to be good candidates to me.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here: (1) going brute force with differentiation to see which of these you can get to satisfy the PDE, $(\partial_{tt}-c^2\partial_{xx})u=0$, for some $c$, or (2) knowing that the solutions to the wave equation must be able to be written in the form $f(x+ct)+g(x-ct)$, which is certainly the more direct and illuminating route. For this latter route, we can immediately rule out cases $1$ and $4$. For case $2$, I recommend looking at your trig identities to rewrite this in an expanded form. And for case $3$, staring at the first and last terms individually. This should get you on the right track.

Comment: Ach of course! number two is perfectly fine. I miscalculated! And was not really sure if I can take these two terms separately (in number 3). Thanks a lot. I think I am fine now. Thank you again.